# Complexity of two nested for loops, where the inner one gets shorter?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am extracting elements from an array by a value of the elements in a specific order, and not able to find the correct O() runtime (nor any other).

The code can be expressed as follows:

```
while (not arr.isEmpty()):
    for (n : arr):    
         //Do stuff
         remove arr[n]
```

But I have not been able to say what the actual function  would look like.

Comment: With that indentation I would assume all elements are removed by the for loop and the while is superfluous, so I would get O(n). If there was a remove first or last outside the for (inside while), then you would get O(n^2). But my assumption seems to be correct because n isn't defined outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The sum should just be sum over (m-j), without the `m*`. You can evaluate this sum to m(m+1)/2, which shows the effort is O(m^2).

Comment: I think this is wrong and all elements are removed on the first execution of the for loop, more info in comment below question.

Comment: @maraca you are right, I must admit, I did not look at the program itself so much.